# Diary in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Hi everybody have assignment diary, i had been created my diary but my concern is that, my Professor want us to make 4 Diaries in this file. Kindly help me to add additional diaries inside. i dont have really idea for it. Hope to this site got what I'm looking for

Comment: This is not a proper question for stackoverflow, it's just too broad. Questions should focus on a single, specific problem. "Kindly help me to add additional diaries inside" is not really a single problem, you're asking us to write code for you.

Comment: @BryanOakley apologies if seems unappreciated question. honestly i don't know how ask for this problem however i'm looking idea or any help to do it.

Comment: Have you tried simply adding more data to `diaryDetails` and `imageLoc`?

Comment: @BryanOakley yes sir i tried adding new `diaryDetails1` and `imageLoc1` doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work" is a bit too vague for us to be able to help.

Comment: Maybe their's something need to add in my GUI as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to expand your diary items, it should be better to put the diary items in external file and read them in your backend library.  Also you should put the bounding checking in the backend library as well.  Then you main application will not need to be changed due to change of the diary items.

I have modified your **backend** (`PhotoDiaryLib.py`) code using class as below:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import json

class PhotoDiary:
    def __init__(self, width=500, height=500):
        self.imageWidth = width
        self.imageHeight = height
        self.current = -1
        self.diary = None
        self.loadDiaries()

    def loadDiaries(self):
        with open('diaries.json') as f:
            self.diaries = json.load(f)

    def getDiaryList(self):
        return self.diaries.keys()

    def getDiaryImage(self, diary):
        return self.diaries[diary]['image']

    def setDiary(self, diary):
        self.diary = diary
        self.diaryDetails = self.diaries[diary]['items']
        self.current = -1

    def getImage(self, imageName):
        originalImage = Image.open(imageName)
        imageRatio = float(originalImage.size[0]) / float(originalImage.size[1])
        if imageRatio > 1:
            targetSize=(self.imageWidth, int(self.imageHeight/imageRatio))
        else:
            targetSize=(int(self.imageWidth*imageRatio), self.imageHeight)
        resizedImage = originalImage.resize(targetSize, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        return ImageTk.PhotoImage(resizedImage)

    def get(self, index):
        ''' get the diary item at given index '''
        if 0 <= index < len(self.diaryDetails):
            self.current = index
            details, imageName = self.diaryDetails[index]
            return details, self.getImage(imageName)
        return None, None

    # navigation functions
    next = lambda self: self.get(self.current+1)
    previous = lambda self: self.get(self.current-1)
```

And `diaries.json` contains something like below:

```
{
  "Fish": {
    "image": "images/fish.jpg",
    "items": [
      ["Test1", "images/1.jpg"],
      ["Test2", "images/2.jpg"],
      ["Test3", "images/3.jpg"],
      ["Test4", "images/4.png"]
    ]
  },
  "Birds": {
    "image": "images/birds.jpg",
    "items": [
      ...
    ]
  },
  "Mammals": {
    "image": "images/mammals.jpg",
    "items": [
      ...
    ]
  },
  "Snakes": {
    "image": "images/snakes.jpg",
    "items": [
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

You can add more items into the JSON file.

Then modify your main application to cater the change of the backend library:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from PhotoDiaryLib import PhotoDiary

class PhotoDiaryApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mainWindow = Tk()
        self.mainWindow.title("Diary")

        self.pd = PhotoDiary(500, 500)
        self.current = StringVar()

        # diary list
        diaryFrame = Frame(self.mainWindow, bg='blue')
        for i, item in enumerate(self.pd.getDiaryList()):
            imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=self.pd.getDiaryImage(item))
            btn = Radiobutton(diaryFrame, text=item, image=imgtk, compound=TOP, indicatoron=0, variable=self.current, value=item)
            btn.config(command=lambda d=item:self.changeDiary(d))
            btn.grid(row=0, column=i, sticky='ew', ipadx=10)
            btn.image = imgtk
            if i == 0: self.current.set(item)
        diaryFrame.pack(fill=X)

        # diary detail frame
        detailFrame = Frame(self.mainWindow)
        detailFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.photoFrame = Frame(detailFrame)
        self.labelFrame = Frame(detailFrame)
        self.controlFrame = Frame(detailFrame)

        self.canvasImage = Canvas(self.photoFrame, width=500, height=500)
        self.canvasImage.pack()
        self.photo = self.canvasImage.create_image(250, 250, image=None)

        self.photoDetails = StringVar()
        self.photoLabel = Label(self.labelFrame, textvariable=self.photoDetails)
        self.photoLabel.pack()

        self.previousButton = Button(self.controlFrame, command=self.previousEntry, text="Previous", width=10)
        self.previousButton.pack(side='left')
        self.previousNext = Button(self.controlFrame, command=self.nextEntry, text="Next", width=10)
        self.previousNext.pack(side='left')

        self.photoFrame.pack()
        self.labelFrame.pack()
        self.controlFrame.pack(pady=10)

        # show first diary
        self.changeDiary(self.current.get())

        self.mainWindow.mainloop()

    def changeDiary(self, diary):
        #print(self.pd.diary, diary)
        if self.pd.diary != diary:
            print('Changed to diary:', diary)
            self.pd.setDiary(diary)
            self.nextEntry()

    def updateDiary(self, details, image):
        ''' update photo details and image '''
        if details and image:
            self.photoDetails.set(details)
            self.photoImage = image
            self.canvasImage.itemconfig(self.photo, image=image)

    def previousEntry(self):
        self.updateDiary(*self.pd.previous())

    def nextEntry(self):
        self.updateDiary(*self.pd.next())

executeWindow = PhotoDiaryApp()
```

Comment: thank you for your code, what i need is to create 4 diaries inside my tkinter. do you have an idea how to it. because the above code is only 1 diary.

Comment: its very cute,  how we can make like the about picture instead of tabs

Comment: You can assign `image` option of `Checkbutton`.  Answer updated.  Make sure the picture size is not too big, around 150x100 is ok.

Comment: Wow sweet cheer up sir, thank you so much. Resolved.